# Change option on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a userscript that will add buttons underneath a dropdown and change the value based on what button is clicked.  There are 3 separate dropdowns given here:

```
<fieldset>
<div style="float: left;">
<div><label>Number of big seeds</label> <select class="form-control" name="big"> <optgroup label="big"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></optgroup> </select></div>
```

```
<div><label>Number of small seeds</label> <select class="form-control" name="small"><optgroup label="small"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></optgroup> </select></div>
```

```
<div><label>Number of tiny seeds</label> <select class="form-control" name="tiny"><optgroup label="tiny"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option> </optgroup> </select></div>
```

And here is my failed attempt at a userscript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Variables for buttons
    var $0 = $('<button type="button" class="0" id="0">0</button>');
    var $1 = $('<button type="button" class="0" id="1">1</button>');
    var $2 = $('<button type="button" class="0" id="2">2</button>');
    var $3 = $('<button type="button" class="0" id="3">3</button>');
    var $4 = $('<button type="button" class="0" id="4">4</button>');
    var $5 = $('<button type="button" class="0" id="5">5</button>');

    var $6 = $('<button type="button" class="1" id="0">0</button>');
    var $7 = $('<button type="button" class="1" id="1">1</button>');
    var $8 = $('<button type="button" class="1" id="2">2</button>');
    var $9 = $('<button type="button" class="1" id="3">3</button>');
    var $10 = $('<button type="button" class="1" id="4">4</button>');
    var $11 = $('<button type="button" class="1" id="5">5</button>');

    var $12 = $('<button type="button" class="2" id="0">0</button>');
    var $13 = $('<button type="button" class="2" id="1">1</button>');
    var $14 = $('<button type="button" class="2" id="2">2</button>');
    var $15 = $('<button type="button" class="2" id="3">3</button>');
    var $16 = $('<button type="button" class="2" id="4">4</button>');
    var $17 = $('<button type="button" class="2" id="5">5</button>');


    //Add buttons
    $('.form-control').eq(0).after($0,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5);
    $('.form-control').eq(1).after($6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11);
    $('.form-control').eq(2).after($12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17);

});

//Click event
$(":button").click(function(){
     var thisClass = parseInt($(this).attr('class'));
     var thisID = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));

     $('.form-control').eq(thisClass).val(thisID);
});
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: So what's the problem, it seems to work fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/zqxrp016/

Comment: Odd, when I try to use it outside of that website the buttons don't change anything.

Comment: On another note, you should strive to avoid using meaningless names like series of numbers, as it makes code very difficult to read and debug. Instead, each thing (variable, function, class, etc) should have a meaningful name that describes what it is or does.

Comment: IDs should be unique, you shouldn't use the same IDs 0 through 5 in each group of buttons. Do you even need the buttons to have IDs?

Comment: Put the `click` event binding inside `$(document).ready()`. Otherwise you're doing it before the elements are added.

Comment: @barmar thank you very much, that worked.  The reason I gave them those IDs was to choose what value I wanted the dropdown to be.  Is there a way to do that without giving them IDs?  Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Use data attributes instead of overloading the class and ID to hold random data. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding the click event immediately, but not adding the buttons until the document is ready. Put the `.click()` call inside `$(document).ready()` after it appends the buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Variables for buttons
    var $0 = $('<button type="button" data-index="0" data-value="0">0</button>');
    var $1 = $('<button type="button" data-index="0" data-value="1">1</button>');
    var $2 = $('<button type="button" data-index="0" data-value="2">2</button>');
    var $3 = $('<button type="button" data-index="0" data-value="3">3</button>');
    var $4 = $('<button type="button" data-index="0" data-value="4">4</button>');
    var $5 = $('<button type="button" data-index="0" data-value="5">5</button>');

    var $6 = $('<button type="button" data-index="1" data-value="0">0</button>');
    var $7 = $('<button type="button" data-index="1" data-value="1">1</button>');
    var $8 = $('<button type="button" data-index="1" data-value="2">2</button>');
    var $9 = $('<button type="button" data-index="1" data-value="3">3</button>');
    var $10 = $('<button type="button" data-index="1" data-value="4">4</button>');
    var $11 = $('<button type="button" data-index="1" data-value="5">5</button>');

    var $12 = $('<button type="button" data-index="2" data-value="0">0</button>');
    var $13 = $('<button type="button" data-index="2" data-value="1">1</button>');
    var $14 = $('<button type="button" data-index="2" data-value="2">2</button>');
    var $15 = $('<button type="button" data-index="2" data-value="3">3</button>');
    var $16 = $('<button type="button" data-index="2" data-value="4">4</button>');
    var $17 = $('<button type="button" data-index="2" data-value="5">5</button>');


    //Add buttons
    $('.form-control').eq(0).after($0,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5);
    $('.form-control').eq(1).after($6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11);
    $('.form-control').eq(2).after($12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17);

    //Click event
    $(":button").click(function(){
         var thisIndex = $(this).data('index');
         var thisValue = $(this).data("value");

         $('.form-control').eq(thisIndex).val(thisValue);
    });
});
```

You also shouldn't give duplicate IDs to elements. I've changed it to use a data attribute. And while it's OK to duplicate classes, using them just to hold data about the element is not really appropriate, so I've changed them to data attributes as well.